# How to retry pipeline (not individual jobs) in GitLab via the UI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Basically I am looking for the retry button for the pipeline triggered, but all I see is a retry button for the individuals jobs of that pipeline. I don't want to have to push a commit just to retry a pipeline.
[Reference screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKnjI.png)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can retry the latest push on the pipeline by going to:

- `CI/CD -> Pipelines -> Run Pipeline -> Select the branch to run.`

Otherwise, as you've mentioned, you'd have to manually press the retry button for each individual job for the pipeline (for a pipeline that isn't the latest).

Comment: However, this may not work when you have rules in your Pipeline for how the pipeline is triggered - for example `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"`. If so, you need to add also "web". [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules)

Comment: This only works if you want to reference a commit that is the latest in the branch as opposed to any pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

[GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#retry-a-downstream-pipeline-from-the-pipeline-graph) (June 2022) should help:

> ### Retry a downstream pipeline from the pipeline graph
>
> Previously, to retry a downstream pipeline, you had to navigate to the pipeline and select retry.
>
> This worked, but was a challenging experience when there were multiple
> downstream pipelines.
> You had to go into every individual pipeline you
> wanted to retry and find the retry option, which was cumbersome.
>
> In this release, we’ve improved the user experience by adding an **option to retry downstream pipelines directly from the pipeline graph, without the need to go into each pipeline’s details page**.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_1/trigger.png -- Retry a downstream pipeline from the pipeline graph]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/354974).>